# Is there any auto increment property for field in Oracle? without using sequence and trigger

Tags: oracle

Is there any auto increment property for field in Oracle  without using sequence and trigger ?
I am creating oracle database table using **TOAD** editor, I want add column with auto increment on, so is there any auto increment property for field? without creating sequence and adding trigger for table.

Comment: Why wouldnt you consider using `sequence`?

Comment: there is in 12c, but in anything earlier than that you need to use a sequence + trigger.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I'm not sure, but I believe in 12c you will still need a sequence - it's just that the syntax for setting the default for a column will be enhanced to allow specifying a sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop. The sequences were created just for do that.

Comment: You could create another table to store the current sequence number, and read and increment it in each new insertion, but you still need to use triggers, so... no advantage at all.